# Replace button with another button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a CV builder, and I already made a button with jQuery to add and delete a form, but when I add, it just goes down, so I can add more, but the first form stays there, and I cannot delete the first form. 
Example
[image: The add button is there (Dodajte)]

You see how it goes down, and I need a button so I can remove the first one also:

[image: You see how it goes down, and I need a button so I can remove the first one also]

As you can see in the pictures, i add a form, and a form comes up, but the add button moves down, as it should, because I put it aside of the div. But I need to add a red button to delete the first form, if someone wants to.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add-more").click(function(){
    var html = $(".copy").html();
    $(".after-add-more").after(html);
  });
  
  $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){
    $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
  });
});

});

})(this.jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-xl-12">
  <div id="test1" class="dashboard-box">

    <!-- Headline -->
    <div class="headline">
      <h3><i class="icon-material-outline-school"></i> Obrazovanje</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content with-padding">
      <div class="forma">
        <div class="row">
          <label class="control-label col-xl-12" for="ContactNo"></label>
          <div class="col-xl-12">
            <div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <label>Institucija</label>
                  <input name="cv_obrazovanje_institucija[]" type="text" placeholder="Upišite vašu instituciju">

                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <label>Zvanje</label>
                  <input name="cv_obrazovanje_zvanje[]" type="text" placeholder="Nivo znanja veštine, opširniji opis...">

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <label>Početak obrazovanja</label><input type="date" name="cv_obrazovanje_pocetak[]">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <label>Kraj obrazovanja</label><input type="date" name="cv_obrazovanje_kraj[]">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input name="cv_obrazovanje_trenutno_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="chekcbox">
                <label for="chekcbox"><span class="checkbox-icon"></span>Trenutno obrazovanje</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Dugme za dodavanje -->
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button" style="padding-left: 15px;"><span class="button ripple-effect">Dodajte</span></button>
          </div>

          <!-- Dugme za dodavanje -->
          <div class="copy hide" style="display: none;">
            <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <label>Institucija</label>
                  <input name="cv_obrazovanje_institucija" type="text" placeholder="Upišite vašu instituciju">

                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <laabel>Zvanje</label>
                    <input name="cv_obrazovanje_zvanje" type="text" placeholder="Nivo znanja veštine, opširniji opis...">

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <label>Početak obrazovanja</label><input type="date" name="cv_obrazovanje_pocetak">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <label>Kraj obrazovanja</label><input type="date" name="cv_obrazovanje_kraj">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input name="cv_obrazovanje_trenutno_checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chekcbox2">
                <label for="chekcbox2"><span class="checkbox-icon"></span>Trenutno obrazovanje</label>
              </div>

              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><span class="button ripple-effect" style="background-color: #B31C1C;">Ukloni</span></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Button -->
  <div class="col-xl-12">
    <a href="#" class="button ripple-effect big margin-top-30">Snimite promene</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: You have console errors due to the extra closing parentheses and braces. Removing them seems to resolve the primary problem. Please see [ask] and revise your post to ask something more specific.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".add-more").click(function() {
    var html = $(".copy").html();
    if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
      console.log("Adding Button");
      $("<div>", {
        class: "input-group-btn"
      }).appendTo($(".row:eq(0) .input-group:eq(0)").eq(0));
      $("<button>", {
        class: "btn btn-danger remove",
        type: "button"
      }).html("<span class='button ripple-effect' style='background-color: #B31C1C;'>Ukloni</span>").appendTo($(".row:eq(0) .input-group:eq(0) .input-group-btn"));
      $(this).addClass("clicked");
    }
    $(".after-add-more").after(html);
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<div class="col-xl-12">
  <div id="test1" class="dashboard-box">
    <!-- Headline -->
    <div class="headline">
      <h3><i class="icon-material-outline-school"></i> Obrazovanje</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content with-padding">
      <div class="forma">
        <div class="row">
          <label class="control-label col-xl-12" for="ContactNo"></label>
          <div class="col-xl-12">
            <div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <label>Institucija</label>
                  <input name="cv_obrazovanje_institucija[]" type="text" placeholder="Upišite vašu instituciju">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <label>Zvanje</label>
                  <input name="cv_obrazovanje_zvanje[]" type="text" placeholder="Nivo znanja veštine, opširniji opis...">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <label>Početak obrazovanja</label><input type="date" name="cv_obrazovanje_pocetak[]">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <label>Kraj obrazovanja</label><input type="date" name="cv_obrazovanje_kraj[]">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input name="cv_obrazovanje_trenutno_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="chekcbox">
                <label for="chekcbox"><span class="checkbox-icon"></span>Trenutno obrazovanje</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Dugme za dodavanje -->
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button" style="padding-left: 15px;"><span class="button ripple-effect">Dodajte</span></button>
          </div>
          <!-- Dugme za dodavanje -->
          <div class="copy hide" style="display: none;">
            <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <label>Institucija</label>
                  <input name="cv_obrazovanje_institucija" type="text" placeholder="Upišite vašu instituciju">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <laabel>Zvanje</label>
                    <input name="cv_obrazovanje_zvanje" type="text" placeholder="Nivo znanja veštine, opširniji opis...">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <label>Početak obrazovanja</label><input type="date" name="cv_obrazovanje_pocetak">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-3">
                  <label>Kraj obrazovanja</label><input type="date" name="cv_obrazovanje_kraj">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input name="cv_obrazovanje_trenutno_checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chekcbox2">
                <label for="chekcbox2"><span class="checkbox-icon"></span>Trenutno obrazovanje</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><span class="button ripple-effect" style="background-color: #B31C1C;">Ukloni</span></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Button -->
  <div class="col-xl-12">
    <a href="#" class="button ripple-effect big margin-top-30">Snimite promene</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems you only want to add the button the first click. We can check to see if a Class exists as a quick check, if it does NOT exists, we can perform the one-time action, and add the Class.

Then it is just a matter of adding the proper elements.

Comment: Yes, that works, but when you delete the first form, the green button doesnt work no more. @Twisty